# How to parameterise a functions argument tuple in Typescript

Tags: generics, functional-programming, typescript

Using Typescript 1.4, say I have a higher-order function with the signature:

```
interface F<A,B> {
    (a: (...x:any[]) => A): (...x:any[]) => B
}
```

Function 'F' takes function 'a' which has a set of parameters 'x'. Function 'F' returns a new function which has exactly the same set of args as function 'a'.

I've been trying to find a way to express this in Typescript, but i'm coming up short. For example:

```
interface F<X extends Array<any>,A,B> {
    (a: (...x:X) => A): (...x:X) => B
}
```

the compiler just complains with: `error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.`

Although that doesn't feel right anyway, even if it did compile. I guess i'd really need something like:

```
interface F<X extends Tuple,A,B> {
    (a: (...x:X) => A): (...x:X) => B
}
```

Anyone know if this kind of thing is even possible with Typescript currently (1.4 at time of writing)? or any suggestions?

---

**Example:**

*(NOTE: This is not my actual use-case, i'm only using logging here as a simple example - please don't focus on that aspect)*

```
// a higher-order function that takes any function and
// returns a new function which takes the same args
// passing them to the original fn and logging the args along with the result

function f(a:(...x:any[]) => any): (...x:any[]) => void {
    return (...x:any[]) => {
        console.log('('+x.join(',')+') => ', a.apply(undefined, x));
    }
}

function a(j:string, k:number): boolean {
    return j === String(k);
}

var b = f(a);

b("1", 1);
b("a", 2);
```

console output:

```
(1,1) =>  true
(a,2) =>  false
```

So this works, but the derived function 'b' has the implied signature of:

```
(...x:any[]) => void
```

ideally i'd like it to have the same arguments as function 'a' ie:

```
(j: string, k: number) => void
```

I know I could explicitly define that, but it's very verbose and not at all ideal, kind of defeats the point of having the strong typing in the first place:

```
var b: (j:string, k:number) => void = f(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

To wrap a function with another that has different return type, one hacky trick is possible with overloading:

```js
function wrap<R>(fn0: ()=> any, p:(f,a)=>R): () => R;
function wrap<R,T>(fn1: (t:T)=> any, p:(f,a)=>R): (t:T) => R;
function wrap<R, T, U>(fn2: (t:T, u:U)=> any, p:(f,a)=>R): (t:T,u:U) => R;
function wrap<R, T, U, V>(fn3: (t:T, u:U, v:V)=> any, p:(f,a)=>R): (t:T,u:U, v:V) => R;
function wrap<R, T, U, V, X>(fn4: (t:T, u:U, v:V, x:X)=> any, p:(f,a)=>R): (t:T,u:U, v:V, x:X) => R;
// ...
function wrap<R>(fn: Function, proc:Function):Function {
 return (...args) => proc(fn, args);
}

// wrap is called with two functions fn and proc
// result is a function with argument types from fn and return type of proc 

function serialize(fn, args):string {
  return JSON.stringify(fn(...args))
}

function foo(a:number,b:string) {
  return true;
}

var wrapped = wrap(foo,serialize)
// type is (a:number,b:string) => string
```

Be careful, it will work only for functions with limited number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> Function 'F' takes function 'a' which has a set of parameters 'x'. Function 'F' returns a new function which has exactly the same set of args as function 'a'.

The specification is a bit unclear, but based on my understanding of what you meant, Here is a sample

```
// Function 'F' takes function 'a' which has a set of parameters 'x'
// and returns a new function which has exactly the same set of args as function 'a'
function F<A extends Function>(a:A):A{
    return a;
}

var foo = F(function(a:number,b:number):void{});

foo (1,3); // okay 
foo(1); // ERROR
```

**UPDATE**

An example for your use case:

```
function f<A extends Function>(a:A):A {
    var newFunc = (...x:any[]) => {
        console.log('('+x.join(',')+') => ', a.apply(undefined, x));
        return null;
    }
    return <any>newFunc;
}

function a(j:string, k:number): boolean {
    return j === String(k);
}

var b = f(a);

b("1", 1);
b("a", 2);
b('123','123'); // ERROR
```

Note: We've capture both the arguments *and* the return type. I don't see a way to capture *just the arguments*.

Comment: I'm trying to write the type specification for a higher-order function that returns a function which has the exact same argument types as the function passed into the higher-order function. The higher-order function doesn't care what the actual args are, it just needs to specify that the function it returns has the same args.

Comment: @MarkGibson `type specification for a higher-order function` =>  `type specification == F` ,  `higher-order function == F` right?

Comment: @MarkGibson is this what you are asking : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2284 ?

Comment: No, the function returned by the higher-order function may have a different return type to that passed in, the only commonality is their arguments. I'll add an example to my question.

Comment: Ah, thanks @basarat, i see where you are coming from now, but as you say its the capturing of _just the arguments_ that's causing my headache.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible to express this in the TypeScript type system. It's a long standing issue which you can follow on https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/212 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453